# SQL query to aggreate the results

Tags: mysql, sql, function

A single Site has multple PODs and Each POD has a status. The data is in a Table as shown below:

```
Store   POD Status  
A001    S101    OK  
A001    S102    OK  
A001    S103    OK  
A002    S201    OK  
A002    S202    Critical  
A002    S203    OK  
A003    S301    OK  
A003    S302    OK  
A003    S303    Critical  
A004    S401    Warning  
A004    S402    OK  
A004    S403    OK  
A005    S501    OK  
A005    S502    OK  
A005    S503    OK  
A006    S601    OK  
A006    S602    OK  
A006    S603    Critical  
A007    S701    OK  
A007    S702    OK  
A007    S703    OK
```

Calculate the site status such that  site should report Critical if any one of the PODs in a site has Critical Status, else if should report Warning if any one of the PODs in a site has warning,

```
Expected Output  
A001 OK  
A002 Critical  
A003 Critical  
A004 Warning  
A005 OK  
A006 Critical  
A007 OK
```

What should be SQL query to get the expected output ?

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: I am new to SQL and was looking into procedure/function and it was becoming complicated. I am sure there must a better and simple way to get the required results. Hence this query.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `ELT` and `conditional aggregation`:

```
SELECT Store, ELT(MAX(CASE WHEN Status='OK' THEN 1
                       WHEN status='Warning' THEN 2
                       WHEN status='Critical' THEN 3 END)
            , 'OK', 'Warning', 'Critical') AS output
FROM tab
GROUP BY Store;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=45a0150539357ec01610be0b0a1e1154)**

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
  store,
  ELT(
    MAX(CASE status WHEN 'OK'       THEN 1
                    WHEN 'Warning'  THEN 2
                    WHEN 'Critical' THEN 3
                                    ELSE 4 END),
    'OK',
    'Warning',
    'Critical',
    'Unknown'
  )
    AS final_status
FROM
  yourTable
GROUP BY
  store
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use *correlation* approach:

```
select Store, (select t1.Status
               from table t1
               where t1.Store = t.Store
               order by (case when t1.Status = 'Critical' 
                              then 1  
                              when t1.Status = 'Warning' 
                              then 2
                              when t1.Status = 'OK' 
                              then 3
                         end)
                limit 1 
               ) as Status  
from table t
group by Store;
```